# PHP fwrite() , could not fill txt

Tags: php, file, newline, fwrite

after code execute my file look like this:

```
1.info
2.
3.info
4.
5.info
....
```

I tried with different mode in fopen but still the same.

```
<?php

$file = 'data.txt';
$lines = file($file);

$newArr = array();
$f = fopen($file,'r+');
foreach($lines as $value){
    $newArr[] = $value;
}
    unset($newArr[$_GET['id']-1]);

foreach($newArr as $vv){
    fwrite($f, $vv.PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me your intentions?

Comment: I have an index file where i show all of my data in the file.txt , and this is my delete.php, i want after unset an eleement of the file.txt to fill file.txt with the new elements using fwrite , but , like im saying after fwrite($f, $vv.PHP_EOL) , my file,txt is like this:

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is the same and should work:

```
$file  = 'data.txt';
$lines = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

unset($lines[$_GET['id']-1]);

file_put_contents($file, $lines);
```

For whatever reason using fwrite():

```
$file  = 'data.txt';
$lines = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

unset($lines[$_GET['id']-1]);

$f = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($f, implode($lines));

/*
foreach($lines as $vv) {
    fwrite($f, $vv);
}
*/
```

Comment: yes with file_put_contents works , but i want to do it with fwrite :)